# Elimnar caracter de una cadena back slash c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy recibiendo desde un api en un campo de correo un email con un `\u001` y luego el correo, un ejemplo de lo que recibo es el siguiente `\u001fabricioyjon@gmail.com`, haciendo pruebas locales sin ejecutar mi proyecto donde sucede esto pude solventarlo de la siguiente manera

código ejemplo:

```
string str = @"\u001amauriciocyjon@gmail.com";
str = str.Replace("\\","");
```

pero cuando llega del api y lo seteo a un objeto como le concateno el `@` para luego poder reemplazar el caracter o si conocen otra forma de eliminarlo estoy atento
despues que llamo al api hago algo similar a esto

```
var ModelPlv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PolizasVehiculos>>(opolizasVehiculos);
```

como podria detecto que mi primer caracter es un `\` y como le concatenaria la `@` para luego hacer el replace?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo q tienes

Comment: Si dices que tu problema es `\u001`, porque no haces el replace directamente a ese valor?, de esta manera `str = str.Replace("\\u001","");`, y en tu código solo deserializas el objeto, pero no mencionas que API estás consumiendo, ni cuál es tu JSON, deberías compartir más código

Comment: no entiendo porque queres concatenarle un @ que es algo que esta en el codigo, y no forma parte del string... no termino de entender porque no haces el replace directamente.. creo que tenes otra confusion aca.. pero no logro detectar cual es...

Answer (score 1):

El carácter \u001a que te esta apareciendo antes de tu email pertene a unicode el cual si lo traduces te da un signo de interrogación que te esta inidicando que eso que esta antes de tu email no es un carácter reconocido. Te recomendaria que primero valides que te estan enviado para poder aplicarle un mejor replace ya que ahora es con este carácter pero más adelante te puede dar con otros.

[image: https://www.online-toolz.com/langs/es/tool-es-text-unicode-entities-convertor.html]